# onclick page goes to top (have to scroll back down to content)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi have a page that has some javascript events basically I have the
accordion effects in a page with repeating data...It is fine until I get
close to the bottom of the screen and expand the page. Next thing I
know I am back up towards the top of the page and have to scroll down
to read the text. I know there is a way to hold the page's position,
but what function(s) would I be looking at?

Here is my JS:

```
    $('.accord-btn').on("click", function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Right now it will to go the top page but the Accordion Panel is still at the bottom, What i want to do is when i click the accordion panel, the panel will be the top og the page, i hope this helps. thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: you'll have to give the target div coordinates in window.scrollTo(), as 0,0 reflects the starting of screen its behaving so

Comment: @AakashJain, please show me your idea. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your accordion scenario as a generic one, here's how I'd go for it

```
<style>
    div{display: none;}
    p{cursor:pointer;}
</style>

<script>
    $("p").on("click",function(){
        $(this).next('div').toggle();
        window.scroll(0,$(this).offset().top);
    });
</script>

<p>Accordion Trigger</p>
<div>
    Content block....
</div>
```

Or you can use anchor tags instead of paragraphs as triggers, giving each an id and setting its target as its own id, which will scroll the page to that id

```
<a id="block1" href="#block1">Accordion Trigger</a>
<div>
    Content block....
</div>
```

Or else you can use jqueryui's accordion widget as a direct solution to it.

Comment: i added animation to this, and it seems its not working.

Comment: animation as in adding speed to the scrolling event? If so, you can try $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top,}, 700), replacing that window.scroll line.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the accordion on click,

(HTML/CSS is just for supporting demo)

```js
$('.accord-btn').on("click", function(){
    $(this).get(0).scrollIntoView();
});
```

```css
.accord-btn{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#000;
}
.container{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:scroll;
  padding-top:300px;
  padding-bottom:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="accord-btn">content</div>
</div>
```

`.offset()` retrieves the current position of the element relative to the document. `.top` refers to the distance from the top of the page.

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately its not working on my end.

Comment: yes, it did not scroll. but i got your point. i just cant figure out what function to use. thanks man.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, `.scrollTo()` actually takes 2 arguments. However, vanilla JS actually has a `scrollIntoView()` function that works as well.

Comment: i understand, Thats a great example. please try to use Bootstrap accordion with 6 or more panels. thanks